# How can sum of FTW->base and some string (path) returns a string?

Tags: c, posix

I call `nftw()` function like this:

```
nftw("/sys/class/tty", opearate_on_tty_item, 1, flags)
```

and function `nftw()` executes function `operate_on_tty_item()` for every item that it finds in the folder `/sys/class/tty`.

Function `operate_on_tty_item()` gets argumments directly from `nftw()` and it checks if current `/sys/class/tty/<device>` device has subfolder `device/driver` *(this means it is a physical device)* and prints this device in a slightly different format i.e. `/dev/<device>`. The function itself looks like this:

```
static int opearate_on_tty_item(const char *path, const struct stat *buffer, int flags, struct FTW *ftw_structure)
{

    max_sub_directories = 1;

    // If depth is higher than max_sub_directories, ignore this field and advance to the next file.
    if (ftw_structure->level > max_sub_directories) {
        // Tell nftw() to continue and take next item.
        return 0;
    }
    // Concatenate string of the object's path, to which we append "/device/driver".
    strcat(directory_concatenation, path);
    strcat(directory_concatenation, "/device/driver");

    // Open the directory stored in concatenated string and check if it exists
    if ((directory = opendir(directory_concatenation))) {

        // Reset concatenated string to null string.
        directory_concatenation[0] = '\0';

        // Concatenate string.
        strcat(directory_concatenation, "/dev/");
        strcat(directory_concatenation, path + ftw_structure->base);

        printf("%s\n", directory_concatenation);
    }
    // Close the opened directory.
    closedir(directory);

    // Reset concatenated string to null string.
    directory_concatenation[0] = '\0';

    return 0;

}
```

The thing I don't understand here is the line:

```
strcat(directory_concatenation, path + ftw_structure->base);
```

This line summs `const char * path` and `ftw_structure->base`. But the `printf()` that follows

```
printf("%s\n", directory_concatenation);
```

prins a string *(for example `/dev/ttyUSB0`)*! How is this possible? How is this string created using the sum operation of a constant character pointer and an integer?

I am completely confused because FTW member FTW.base is defined in POSIX header `ftw.h` like this *(it is an integer)*:

```
/* Structure used for fourth argument to callback function for `nftw'.  */
struct FTW
  {
    int base;
    int level;
  };
```

So how does POSIX compliant system know to display the string? How is this even calculated?

Comment: I do not understand your confusion. Would you be able to address more specific questions? Do you know what a C string is? Are you confused by pointer arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this possible?

It seems like `directory_concatenation` is a pointer that points to a memory that contains `/dev/ttyUSB0` followed by a zero byte.

> How is this string created using the sum operation of a constant character pointer and an integer?

The value of the integer is added to the address stored by the pointer, incrementing the pointer value. Because from the documentation:

> The fourth argument that nftw() supplies when calling fn() is a
> structure of type FTW:
>
> ```
> struct FTW {
>     int base;
>     int level;
> };
> ```
>
> *base* is the offset of the filename (i.e., basename component) in the
> pathname given in `fpath`. [...]

The result from the calculation is a pointer to a string that represents the filename of the path. Then `strcat` finds the first zero byte inside the memory pointed to by `directory_concatenation` pointer, **copies** the bytes that represent that filename, one byte after another to the location starting from the zero byte location inside the memory pointed to by `directory_concatenation`. The trailing zero byte is also copied, thus creating a new string with concatenated the value of filename to the previous string.

Comment: So for example... `strcat(directory_concatenation, path + ftw_structure->base);` first takes a character pointer `path` *(that at that moment points to a string  e.g. `/sys/class/tty/<device>`)* and uses pointer arithmetics to add an integer `ftw_structure->base` to the pointer. So for example if `ftw_structure->base = 1` then pointer points to the next character and it actually points to the string `sys/class/tty/<device>` (without `/`). So according to this logic if `ftw_structure->base = 15`, string becomes `<device>`. And this is then concatenated by `strcat()` to create `/dev/<device>`.

Comment: Yes,  yes, yes, yes

Comment: Thank you for this feedback as well. It is of great help!